# Setting (selecting) drop-down elements from links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many SELECT elements withing one div. I would like to do:

1. Create links from these option values. example:

   `Color: Black Green Pink`...

   `Size: S M L`...

   `Quantity: 1 2 3 4`...
2. When clicked on link that link the value gets selected in combo-box and the value should be displayed on top:

   `Selected: Color - White, Size - S, Quantity - 3`
3. Links should skip the first option (Color, Size ect.).

`
    
        Color:
        Black
        Green
        Pink 
        Orange
        Purple
        White
        Yellow
        Blue
        Navy
        Cream

```
<select name="5043:finopt:1" size=1 >
    <option value="Size:" selected>Size:</option>
    <option value="S" >S</option>
    <option value="M" >M</option>
    <option value="L" >L</option>
    <option value="XL" >XL</option>
</select>

<select name="5043:finopt:1" size=1 >
    <option value="Size:" selected>Quantity</option>
    <option value="1" >1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
    <option value="3" >3</option>
    <option value="4" >4</option>
</select>
```

`

Also the name of the select elements is always different, not always 5043:finopt:1

Comment: How would you like your links to look like? I mean, do you want them to be like for example `<a href="domain.com/page?color=black&size=M&quantity=1">Text here</a>` and when you change the values of the `select` elements the `href` property of the link also changes?

Comment: Links on click will change the drop-down selected element. That's it.

Comment: <a class="select" href="#">[VALUE_FROM_COMBO_BOX]</a>

Comment: <a class="color" href="#">[VALUE_FROM_COMBO_BOX]</a>
...
<a class="size" href="#">[VALUE_FROM_COMBO_BOX]</a>
...
<a class="quantity" href="#">[VALUE_FROM_COMBO_BOX]</a>

Answer (score 0):

First, You have to add a way to identify each dropdown box. Since you said that the their `name` attribute is always different, you have to add another way to identify them. Let's try adding a `data-name` attribute (you can use whatever name you want) to each one of them.

Second, you said that "links should skip the first option". I interpret this as you don't want the user to be able to select the first options (e.g. Color, Size, Quantity). You can make these options non-selectable by adding a `disabled` flag on them.

```
<select name="5043:finopt:1" size=1 data-name="size">
  <option selected disabled>Size:</option>
  ...
</select>
```

To then select the correct values from the dropdown boxes when clicking on the links, you can add this jQuery snippet (this assumes that each link text is always of the form `Selected: Color - White, Size - S, Quantity - 3`):

```
$('a.select').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = $(this).text();
  text = text.substring(text.indexOf(' ') + 1).split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var pair = text[i].trim().split(' - ');
    $('select[data-name="' + pair[0].toLowerCase() + '"]').val(pair[1]);
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

Since the select boxes markup cannot be modified and you wanna select them by their first option, you can do it like this:

```
$('a.select').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = $(this).text();
  text = text.substring(text.indexOf(' ') + 1).split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var pair = text[i].trim().split(' - ');
    var a = $('select').filter(function() {
      return $(this).children().first().text() == pair[0] + ':';
    }).val(pair[1]);
  }
});
```

Comment: 1) `You have to add a way to identify each dropdown box` the cms outputs it automatically. Is there a way to identify them by the first option (Color, Size, Quantity)? 
2) `<option selected disabled>` can't do it, explained in the beginning.

Comment: can you make a live example on jsfiddle? Thanks

Comment: @Skagen sorry for not getting back soon, but anyway here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arnellebalane/yczLs7nu/

Comment: cam you make it so the links get created automatically from the values of select elements?

Comment: @Skagen yes you can. Just listen for the `change` event of each of the  `select` elements, then update the text accordingly.

Comment: I want simmilar example http://jsfiddle.net/TZ464/6/ but this code is focused on div where each div has 1 combo-box. In my case all the comboboxes are in one div.